# avoid passing around temporary Promise objects

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, puppeteer

I'm automating chrome using puppeteer and I find myself doing the following very often

```
// set up a promise that will resolve once some specific 
// network response (xhr for example) shows up
const eventPromise = checkForThing();
await page.click(SUBMIT_BUTTON);
await eventPromise;
```

The reason for the order is that I don't want to miss the network response that will occur as a result of the page click.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to have temporarily promise objects all over the place because of this. Ideally, the code should just read

```
await page.click()
await checkForThing();
```

`checkForThing()` looks something like

```
    function checkForThing(page) {       

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        function handleLoginResponse(response) {
            try {
                if (response.resourceType() === 'xhr') {
                    return;
                }
                const request = response.request();


                if (response && response.status() === 401) {
                    reject(loginFailureMessage);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
                page.off('response', handleLoginResponse);

            } catch (error) {
                reject(loginFailureMessage);
            }
        };

        page.on('response', handleLoginResponse);
    });
}
```

Comment: The code isn't valid. What's `function checkForThing(){

 function handleLoginResponse(response) {` thing? `resolve` implies that there's `new Promise` somewhere but it isn't shown. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: my bad. just fixed it up.

Comment: I would expect `await page.click(); await checkForThing()` or `page.click(); await checkForThing()`  to work. Just because a response doesn't happen immediately and there shouldn't be race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple Promise.all that awaits for both of them?

```
await Promise.all([page.click(), checkForThing()])
```

This way it will resolve finally no matter which order they are in.

Comment: My concern was that if I don't register the `response` event promise before I click the button, I might miss the response event that occurs when the button is clicked.

Comment: This might actually be the best option i think. The puppeteer docs mention something similar to this for [click](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.6.1&show=api-pageclickselector-options)

Comment: Reverse it: `[checkForThing(), page.click()]`. Now you’ll catch any response events that occur when the button is clicked too.